# Where does this permanent SQLExpress connectionstring come from (not web.config)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, connection-string

Today I noticed that in my `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` the very first instance is `.\SQLEXPRESS`. I remembered explicitly removing this entry from my web.config so I checked again, but didn't find a thing. Then I did a search over my entire solution, not a single match.
Where the hell is this connection string coming from and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's in there by default, pulled in from your machine config file.  To get rid of it just put

```
<clear />
```

Above your first connection string to remove it.

Comment: That's probably just that little better then removing it from the machine.config. Don't really get why you would put connection strings in machine.config in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the machine.config.

However you may remove it, if you wish.